# Why does XmlTextReader fail on calling an unsupported Stream.Length?

Tags: c#, .net, xmltextreader

I have an XmlTextReader, and I pass it in a System.Net.ConnectStream. If I enter the debugger, I can see that ConnectStream does not support the Length property and this throws a NotSupportedException.

Now, I subclass Stream and pass in an instance of my class. My class also throws NotSupportedException on the get() accessor of Length, but this time all my unit tests fail with a NotSupportedException.

**The XmlTextReader documentation does not say it requires a Stream supporting Length, and it clearly *can* use one that doesn't - what is going on?**

(This is .NET 3.5 Client)

Comment: What does your `Stream.CanSeek` return? It would be helpful if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Have you tried XmlDocument.  Super easy to use if you're not using big chunks of XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet - My Stream returned CanSeek as true (which it can, in the data it already has - it just doesn't know how much data it may recieve) unlike ConnectStream. If I change this to false, XmlTextReader works fine. Thanks for the pointer! If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mr.B I am actually using XmlSerialiser, passing in an XmlTextReader (in order to use the Deserialise() method) but thanks for the heads up about XmlDocument, I'll keep that in mind for future applications.

Comment: @Mr.B: It's not *nearly* as easy to use as LINQ to XML, IMO. I would take XDocument over XmlDocument any day of the week - particularly if namespaces are involved.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `Stream` returns true from [`CanSeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek), it assumed that `Length`, `SetLength`, `Position` and `Seek` are all supported. Some code may test `CanSeek` and use the result to optimize its behaviour - as seems to be the case here. When you return `true` from `CanSeek` but then throw an exception in `Length`, that's breaking the not-terribly-well-documented contract of `Stream`.

If you can't support the `Length` property, it's best to return `false` from `CanSeek`.